# How to change field changeNote from IVersionable behavior to be required

Tags: plone, behavior, overriding, dexterity

I have use case where users should allways fill the changeNote field when saving changes on content. Is it possible (TTW) to change the changeNote field from IVersionable behavior to be required ? And if not, is it possible in code ? What is the best way to override standard fields properties from foreign/preinstalled behaviors ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's another way to do this but you may override the value of the `required` attribute by implementing something like this in your code:

```py
(Pdb) from plone.app.versioningbehavior.behaviors import IVersionable
(Pdb) IVersionable
<SchemaClass plone.app.versioningbehavior.behaviors.IVersionable>
(Pdb) IVersionable['changeNote']
<zope.schema._bootstrapfields.TextLine object at 0x7fe45a60f550>
(Pdb) IVersionable['changeNote'].required
False
(Pdb) IVersionable['changeNote'].required = True
(Pdb) IVersionable['changeNote'].required
True
```